# Std::vector<struct> to const std::vector<const struct>*

Tags: c++, vector

I have private variable `std::vector<some struct>` Can i somehow pass the vector to function return value, but with no "write" access, so you will not be able to add new elements into it, and you won't be able to modify the elements(e.g. `const std::vector<some const struct>*`. How can i do that? The only idea i have is to create a new vector with constant pointers to existing elements. Is there a better solution?

Comment: Just `return &the_vector;`? Although it might be more idiomatic to return two `const_iterators`.

Comment: @juanchopanza In that case, u will be able to modify every element in that vector

Comment: Really? How would you do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't modify the elements of a vector via a pointer or reference to `const` vector. So the following would be safe:

```
const std::vector<some_type>* get_pstuff() const { return &the_vector; }
const std::vector<some_type>& get_rstuff() const { return the_vector; }
```

On the other hand, it might be more idiomatic to return const_iterators to the begin and end of the vector:

```
std::vector<some_type>::const_iterator cbegin() const { return the_vector.cbegin(); }
std::vector<some_type>::const_iterator cend() const { return the_vector.cend(); }
```

Comment: You can't add or remove from the vector, but you can still modify the instances of each `some_type` object.

Comment: @Lochemage No, you can't.

Comment: Sorry, I mistook `some_type` to be a pointer to an object, you are correct in this case.

Comment: @Lochemage I thought the same. But [this](http://ideone.com/tpSmfg) shows it is not possible. I wasn't correct. ah Anyway thx

Comment: @juanchopanza I have one more question. Why is better to return interators insead of a vector?

Comment: These solution may well be what is desired. However, they do defeat one possible goal of the class: hiding the internal representation in this variable. Since your clients are using references/pointers/iterators into your private variable, you are exposing the fact that there _is_ such a variable; you are giving up to possibility to ever change this implementation.

Comment: @Quest It is very common to use std library containers with algorithms that take a pair of iterators. It is also an attempt to hide *some* of the internal details of the class. Exporting iterators shows less of the inner structure than exporting a reference or pointer to a data member.